# python group chat id

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a chat dataset and I want to make a conversation group and count how many messages did they send.

Here is my data. This data is the chat log of  "ID", whose name is Jimmy.

```
Sender      Receiver   Text
ID          person1    HI
person1     ID         Hello~
ID          person1    My name is Jimmy
person1     ID         Nice to meet you!
ID          person1    Nice to meet you, too
ID          person2    Hi
person1     ID         Hi there
ID          person2    My name is Jimmy
person1     ID         My name is Abi
ID          person2    Nice to meet you
...         ....       .....
```

"ID" can chat with more than one guy.
I want to count the number of messages for each conversation.
In this case, both conversations have 5 messages.

I have written codes but it looks like inefficient since my data is large.

```
    #chat_df is the dataframe of chat data
    df = []
    total_message =[]
    receiver_id = chat_df["receiver"].unique()
    for x in rid:
        total_message.append(len(chat_df[(chat_df["receiver"] == x) | (chat_df["sender"] == x)]))
        df.append(chat_df[(chat_df["receiver"] == x) | (chat_df["sender"] == x)])
```

Is there a more efficient way to get the pair of two persons' chat data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = chat_df[['Sender','Receiver']].stack().value_counts().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['People','Counts']
print (df1)
    People  Counts
0       ID      10
1  person1       7
2  person2       3
```

EDIT:

```
#get number of all words
chat_df['Len'] = chat_df.Text.str.split().str.len()
#reshape dataframe
chat_df = chat_df.set_index('Len')[['Sender','Receiver']].stack().reset_index(name='People')
print (chat_df)
    Len   level_1   People
0     1    Sender       ID
1     1  Receiver  person1
2     1    Sender  person1
3     1  Receiver       ID
4     4    Sender       ID
5     4  Receiver  person1
6     4    Sender  person1
7     4  Receiver       ID
8     5    Sender       ID
9     5  Receiver  person1
10    1    Sender       ID
11    1  Receiver  person2
12    2    Sender  person1
13    2  Receiver       ID
14    4    Sender       ID
15    4  Receiver  person2
16    4    Sender  person1
17    4  Receiver       ID
18    4    Sender       ID
19    4  Receiver  person2
```

---

```
#groupby by People and aggregate sum and size
chat_df1 = chat_df.groupby('People')['Len'].agg(['size','sum'])
chat_df1.columns = ['Count','Len_words']
chat_df1 = chat_df1.reset_index()
#filter all sizes higher as 5
chat_df1 = chat_df1[chat_df1['Count'] > 5]
print (chat_df1)
    People  Count  Len_words
0       ID     10         30
1  person1      7         21
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I need!
one more question..
if I want to count the number of text on each message for those higher Counts (said over 5), how would you suggest to accomplish it?
Many thanks to you!

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking about your second question and I think there is not better solution as loop by unique values with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: what does mean number of text? count words? or length of text message?

Comment: Sorry for unclear about the question, it means the length of text message, thank you

Comment: Now it is more complicated, please check answer. Also you can upvote - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136528/discussion-between-jimmy15923-and-jezrael).